# Shopify - make list of available variants for display

Tags: arrays, shopify, liquid

I am trying to show what variants are available for each product on a store. While I have the code to do this working, each available variant should be comma separated except for the last one.

I have tried the append string filter, but that includes the last item.

I have tried using {% if forloop.last %} but the code will include the variant even if it is not available.

Here is my code:

```
{% if product.variants.size > 0 and product.available %}
    {% unless product.has_only_default_variant %}
      <span class="sizes-available">
        Sizes in stock:

            {% for variant in product.variants %}
              {% if variant.available %}

                  {{ variant.title | append: ', '}}

              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

      </span>
    {% endunless %}
  {% endif %}
```

If the product has three variants (size A, size B, size C) and size C is out of stock, my desired output is: size A, size B

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer ... needs to be an array to use the join array filter.

Updated code:

```
{% if product.variants.size > 0 and product.available %}
    {% unless product.has_only_default_variant %}
      <span class="sizes-available">
        Sizes in stock:
          {% capture list %}
            {% for variant in product.variants %}
              {% if variant.available %}    
                  {{ variant.title }}
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endcapture %}

          {% assign array = list | split: ' ' %}

          {{ array | join: ', ' }}   
      </span>
    {% endunless %}
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're skipping an unknown number of elements, which could include the first or last element in the list - so we can't rely on `forloop.first` or `forloop.last`, as either one of these might be a skipped element.

An alternate way to approach this situation where you need a comma after every element except the last one is to structure the code like this:

```
{%- assign empty_list = true -%}
{%- for variant in product.variants -%}
  {%- comment -%}Skip the variant if it's not available{%- endcomment -%}
  {%- unless variant.available -%}
    {%- continue -%}
  {%- endunless -%}

  {%- comment -%}Print a comma unless our list is empty{%- endcomment -%}
  {%- unless empty_list -%},{%- endunless -%}
  {%- assign empty_list = false -%}

  {%- comment -%}Now print our new entry{%- endcomment -%}
  <span class="variant-name"> {{ variant.title }}</span>
{%- endfor -%}
```

(Note: In the above example, I included the whitespace-stripping `-`'s in the Liquid tags to remove all the excess line breaks/tabs/spaces between the tags.  See https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/ for more details)